# write a list of ordered dictionaries to a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, ordereddictionary

After reading a CSV file using

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.DictReader(f)
  for line in reader:
    date = line['Date']
```

each line is an OrderedDict

```
OrderedDict([
    ('Date', '2008-03-20'), 
    ('Name', 'Some name'),...)
])
```

I would like to write this list of ordered dictionaries to a csv file in python using the keys of the first dictionary in the list as the column header.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: @ClemensTolboom although the edit is worthwhile, I'm not sure if it's worth bumping a 4-year-old closed question.

Comment: @AdamSmith well the answer was useful so I brushed off the question :) So thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a `csv.DictWriter` object to do all the heavy lifting for you:

```
import csv
with open('spreadsheet.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    fp = csv.DictWriter(outfile, list_of_dicts[0].keys())
    fp.writeheader()
    fp.writerows(list_of_dicts)
```

It creates a new CSV, writes a header line to it so you know what each column represents, then  writes out each dict as a row with all the columns in the same order as the header column.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
header = [key for key in list[0].iterkeys()]
out_file = csv.writer(open("out.csv", "w"))
out_file.write(header)
for line in list:
    out_file.writerow(line.itervalues())
```

Comment: That's dangerous because it assumes that `line.itervalues()` will always return in the same order as `list[0].iterkeys()`. It's safer to assume that dict items will always return in a random order and code defensively for that case.

Comment: if you use OrderedDict, as the original author planned iterkeys and itervalues will return the dicts in the same order